# Mapping List of Probes/Primers/Short Oligos to a Reference Fasta/q

Tags: sequence-alignment, read-mapping, multiple-sequence-alignment, primer

Could you help me bioinformatics SE people.

So I have been duckduckgo-ing up a storm and even consulted the AI overlords and haven't come up with a solid way to do this, but it is so fundamental to bioinformatics that it has to already exists and I don't need to be re-inventing the wheel...

So imagine you have a fasta/q file with a "reference" sequence:

`AATTTTAAAAAAACCCCAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGGAAACCACAAAA`

And a list of short oligo sequences:
`TTTT, CCCC, GGGG`

How would be the best way to map (if that is the right terminology) the short oligos to the reference seq so that a configurable mismatch amount is allowed:

```
  TTTT       CCCC           GGGG    CCCC    
AATTTTAAAAAAACCCCAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGAAAACCACAAAA
```

Blast, BWA and Bowtie2 from my understanding aren't ideal for this because they aren't built for really short sequences, something about them using seeded reference lookup?
Using Smith-Watterman or Needleman-Wunsch technically gets the local aligning right but the mismach allowance is based on score not X total allowed. Plus, iterating over hundreds of oligos and aligning against dozens of large references seems inefficient.
The closest thing I have found to what I'm trying to do is [Sequence Manipulation Suites' Primer Map](https://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/primer_map.html). This tool is almost perfect except a) it is a web tool, not a module I could import into python or incorporate into a CLI and b) does not appear to offer any tolerance for mismatches.

Am I just searching with the wrong vocabulary? This has to be an already solved bioinformatics process right?

Comment: A reference FASTQ is not a thing: A reference sequence is curated in some way, and a curated sequence does not come with quality scores.

Comment: Here is the source code of [Primer Map](https://github.com/paulstothard/sequence_manipulation_suite/blob/master/docs/scripts/primer_map.js) You are not restricted to use it as a web tool only. Moreover you can modify it according to your needs.

Comment: @RamRS this is why I put reference in quotes lol. Basically the bare sequences are parsed out of a fasta/q file and are used as targets to align all the shorter oligos to.

Comment: @M__ I'm trying to determine coverage of a pool of primers against arbitrary target(s)

Comment: @haci Thanks! I cloned a copy and am working on dissecting it and figuring out if it has the ability to be modified for mismatching. Still feel like this is something that already exists and I just don't have the right search terms to find it...

Comment: @RPINerd I don't quite understand what you mean by "coverage of primers" but you might want to check out [primer3](https://primer3.ut.ee/). I used this in the past to design/test a large number of primers. You can customize and run via CLI.

Comment: @haci taking the example I gave in the OP, the "coverage" would be (4 bp * 4 oligos)/ 44 bp target sequence, so about 36%. And taking start stop positions into account I could also make some statistics on the distance between aligned sites

Answer (score 0):

Both of @haci's solutions are very cool:

- [Primer Map](https://github.com/paulstothard/sequence_manipulation_suite/blob/master/docs/scripts/primer_map.js)
- [Primer3 CLI](https://github.com/primer3-org/primer3)

I wasn't aware that Primer3 was available as a CLI (command line interface).

The solution I had in mind was *in silico* PCR one example being [Kelpie](https://github.com/PaulGreenfieldOz/WorkingDogs/tree/master/Kelpie) and the associated paper is [here](https://peerj.com/articles/6174/), however I am not exactly sure about the application of the "primer mapping", but most "primer" applications concern PCR.